# external interface

Tags: javascript, flash, interface, external

I have a calc function in java script that takes three integer parameters, 
following is the AS3 code

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
var para:Array = new Array();
send_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickListener);
function clickListener(eventObj:Object ):void {
    para.push(mean.text);
    para.push(std.text);
    para.push(points.text);
    trace("click > " + para);
    ExternalInterface.call("calc",para );
}
```

is this the right way of doing it and how do i get back 3 arguments back from the javascript and display them in flash?

Comment: You could have just edited your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435763/how-do-i-pass-information-between-flashs-externalinterface-and-javascript

Comment: is this still an issue? otherwise accept the answer so that the question is removed from the 'unanswered' list. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition, you need to register your AS function so that it's available to the container:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("callFlash", myASFunction);
```

Then, from your container (JS), you call the AS function and pass whatever parameters you want to it.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 

    flashObject.callFlash(param1, param2, param3); 
</script> 

... 

<object id="flashObject"...> 
    ... 
    <embed name="flashObject".../> 
</object>
```

Lastly, in AS3, you write the function that will be executed when the container "calls back":

```
function myASFunction(param1:String,param2:String,param3:String):void {
    trace("\n Received call from JS: " + param1 + param2 + param3);
}
```