# flash object: call javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am trying to call a Jscript function from a flash object. I want the function to be called when the animation ends.

Here is the embed code

```
<h1 align="center">  
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" 
        WIDTH="360" HEIGHT="250" id="Yourfilename" ALIGN="center">
    <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="newbanner.swf">
    <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high/><param name="LOOP" value="false" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
    <EMBED src="newbanner.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
           WIDTH="360" HEIGHT="250" loop="false" NAME="newbanner.swf" ALIGN=""
           TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
           PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </EMBED> 
</OBJECT>
</h1>
```

here is the jScript function i want to call:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function mainFunction() {
        var mydiv = document.getElementById('content');
        mydiv.innerHTML = "hello";
    }
</script>
```

here is the action code I add to the last frame of the flash object

```
URLLoader("javascript:mainFunction();");
```

The object loads but the function is not called. I can call the function other ways such as using an "onclick = mainFunction()" event on a button for example. Where am i going wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: here you can see example of using external interface: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439794/external-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use flash.external.ExternalInterface.call ?

Comment: could you give me a quick example of how I would use this please?

Comment: I added the following to the last frame of AS: ExternalInterface.call("mainFunction();"); It still isnt working :(

Comment: it shouldn't be "mainFunction();" just "mainFunction"

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call()

Comment: it shouldn't be "mainFunction();" just "mainFunction" -- this worked thanks